# ReGex for the Postal code

Tags: java, android

I need to pull the 6 digit Postal code from the address.

"51 Bras Basah Road  #01-01 Manulife Centre  Singapore 189554"

The postal code is always 6 digit, but not surely in the last of the address.

Please help me giving a proper "java" regex to get postal code from above address.

Asmi

Comment: Please show your efforts... [Regex tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: You say the postal code may not be the last 6 characters of the address. Provide some examples of such addresses, so the regex can be suitably narrow.

Comment: True, but he hasn't said anything about whether only a postal code could be 6 digits. I was wondering whether perhaps its always the last 6 digit sequence...

Comment: yes it will be always 6 digit, it only for one country

Comment: most possibly postal code is  only one with 6 digit and without any spaces in complete address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can be sure that the postal code is the only 6-digit number in your input, you should be able to get away with:

```
Pattern zipPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6})");
Matcher zipMatcher = zipPattern.matcher("51 Bras Basah Road #01-01 Manulife Centre Singapore 189554");
if (zipMatcher.find()) {
    String zip = zipMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Also see [the API documentation of java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: I have tested my corrected sample code. It works correctly for your example.

Comment: I corrected line 3 to invoke `find()` instead of `matches()`. Which version did you try? What was the input?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple regexp

(.*)((\d){6})$

First group is "51 Bras Basah Road #01-01 Manulife Centre Singapore"
 2nd group is postal code (6digits)

Comment: Doesn't the `$` at the end require the postal code be the last 6 characters? If so, that's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga yes, the postal code is not always in the last of the address, so I would something that will fit that purpose

Comment: @DilumRanatunga right it assume that we have 6 digits from end ($)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that will find the *last* six digit number:

```
((\d{6}.*)*\s)?(\d{6})([^\d].*)?$
```

Of course, you will need to escape the string when compiling the pattern:

```
Pattern postal_code_group3 = Pattern.compile("((\\d{6}.*)*\\s)?(\\d{6})([^\\d].*)?$");
```

You can get the postal code from group 3 of any match.

Note that group 2 forces a whitespace before the postal code, unless the string starts with the postal code.

Group 4 takes care of anything after the postal code, and also prevents a trailing 7-or-more digit number from being matched as the postal code.